# Hover image and appear an icon?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've Created a masonry type portfolio for my website. Now I just want to add an hover effect.(or whatever do my task)

I tried to set div opacity to 1 and at the hover stage set to 0. But I don't need to hide my border. Also I need to add a clickable icon in the middle area when hover the div. Just like this.

[image]

This is my code

```
<a href="#">
 <div class="item i1">
 <img src="/images/epd.jpg" alt="">
 <p class="title">Title</p>
</div>
```

```
.item {
    color: white;
    display: table;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    text-align: center;
    width: 295px;
    margin: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ebebeb;
    opacity: 1;
}

.item:hover {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: so what exact hover effect do you want ?

Comment: Please provide a working example...

Comment: Is it ok to post external link here?

Comment: If i understood, you want a clickable icon to appear when hover on your div : Maybe your div with the opacity changing is not the right div. Indeed you maybe should add a div that contains your icon, and change its opacity (add a container, in other words).

Comment: @MrWeb yes you can post external links, but we prefer a code snippet that is working with minimal code required to show the problem.

Comment: Ah you got that. Let me try this.

Comment: @randy: Take a look at this http://thefoxwp.com/portfolio-masonry-5-bottom-title/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

HTML code....

```
   <div id='parent'>
        <div id='child_one'></div>
        <div id='child_two'style="">
            <a href="http://www.google.com">link
            </a>
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Css

```
        div#parent{width:200px;height:350px;border:1px solid black;position:relative}
        div#child_one{position:absolute;z-index:98;background:red;width:100%;height:100%;}
        div#child_two{z-index:0;position:relative;background:yellow;width:100%;height:100%;}
        div#child_two a{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;right:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;width:30px;height:30px;background:skyblue;}
        div#parent:hover div#child_two{z-index:99}
```

Answer (score 0):

// This Is The Example For Your Question Just You Set Your images And It's Positions.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#anchor').hide();
 $('#imgdiv').mouseover(function(){
 $('#anchor').fadeIn();
 });
  $('#imgdiv').mouseout(function(){
 $('#anchor').fadeOut();
 });
});
```

```css
.img-div{
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:#ccc;
}
.img-div .img{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  
}
.img-div #anchor{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  top:50%;
  left:35%;
  border:1px solid;
}
.img-div #anchor img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-div" id="imgdiv">
 <img src="..img.png" alt="your Image Path Here" class="img"/> 
  <a href="#" id="anchor"><img src="img.jpg" alt="Your Anchor Image Here" /></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Anchor image flashes when hovering over it.

Answer (score 0):

This Is Another Logic Just Use This Example.
But You Give Path In Two Divs ("imgdiv And imgdiv2") Both Are Different .

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#layerid').hide();
 $('#imgdiv').mouseover(function(){
 $('#layerid').fadeIn();
 });
 $('#layerid').mouseout(function(){
 $('#anchor').fadeIn();
 });
 $('#close').click(function(){
 $('#layerid').css('display','none');
 $('#imgdiv').css('display','none');
 });
 $('#imgdiv2').mouseout(function(){
   $('#imgdiv').css('display','none');
   $('#imgdiv').fadeIn();
 }); 
});
```

```css
.img-div{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:#ccc;
  z-index:0;
}
.img-div2{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:#ccc;
  z-index:-1;
}
.img-div2 .img{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  
}
.img-div .img{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  
}
#anchor{
  position:absolute;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  top:50%;
  left:35%;
  border:1px solid;
  z-index:3;
}
#anchor img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.layer{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
  background:#600;
  opacity:0.5;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border:1px solid;
  z-index:2;
}
#close{
 position:absolute;
 top:0px;
 right:20px;
  color:#fff;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="img-div" id="imgdiv">
 <img src="..img.png" alt="your Image Path Here" class="img"/> 
  </div>
<div class="img-div2" id="imgdiv2">
 <img src="..img.png" alt="your Image Path Here" class="img"/> 
  </div>
<div class="layer" id="layerid">
  <span id="close">Close&times;</span>
<a href="#" id="anchor"><img src="img.jpg" alt="Your Anchor Image Here" /></a>
</div>
```